# comparing strings with strcmp-crash

Tags: c, string, generics, pointers

I am experimenting with pointers and strings. In the following code, everything is tested (you can compile and run yourselves), but I keep crashing when I am trying to use
strcmp. The code runs without warnings in codeblocks. Can you please point out my mistake that makes the program crash??

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main() 
    {
        int choice,x=7,k,q,cmp,j=0,i=0,N;
        char v[5],str[80],c[5];
        char *B[11][2]=
        {"-----","0",
         ".----","1",
         "..---","2",
         "...--","3",
         "....-","4",
         ".....","5",
         "-....","6",
         "--...","7",
         "---..","8",
         "----.","9",
         NULL,NULL};

         printf("Give a stream");
         if(gets(str)) printf("%s\n",str);
         fflush(stdin);
         i=0;
         while(str[i])
         {
             q=0;
             j=i+1;
             while(q%5!=0)
             {
                 v[j]=str[j];
                 puts(v);
                 j++;
                 q++;
             }
             printf("Hello");
             for(k=0; k<11; k++)
             {
                 strcpy(c,B[k][0]);
                 printf("%s",c);
                 x=strcmp(v,c);
                 //Problem:
                 printf("%d",c);
                 if(x==0) printf("hi");
             }
             i=i+1;
             j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: This sounds like the time to learn how to use the debugger...

Comment: This doesn't necessarily solve the problem, but v[6],c[6] and v[5]=c[5]='\0'; would be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't filling the `v` with data. The condition `while(q%5!=0)` is false on entry since `q == 0`. This leaves `v` uninitialized, i.e. containing garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

```
strcpy(c,B[k][0]);
```

Now `c` is declared as:

```
char c[5];
```

and `B[k][0]` has 5 characters. Since you want `c` to be a NUL terminated char array, you must  has space to accommodate the NUL char and use `strncpy`

Comment: Arrays in C start from 0. Therefore I put te 5 charactes in 0-4 and then I will put a NULL at position 5.

Comment: @alex777: You don't have a 5th position in an array of size 5.

Answer (score 1):

This program will dump when k=10,because B[10][0] = NULL.strcpy(char *dest, const char *src) will dump when src=null.